# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm write sitemap.config.

```
        <siteMapNode title="Shipping rate" nopResource="Admin.Configuration.Shipping.Rate" controller="Shipping" action="ConfigureProvider?systemName=Shipping.ByWeight"   />           


      </siteMapNode>
```

This is the shipping controller function which I want to call.

```
public ActionResult ConfigureProvider(string systemName)
        {
            if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageShippingSettings))
                return AccessDeniedView();

            var srcm = _shippingService.LoadShippingRateComputationMethodBySystemName(systemName);
            if (srcm == null)
                //No shipping rate computation method found with the specified id
                return RedirectToAction("Providers");

            var model = srcm.ToModel();
            string actionName, controllerName;
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues;
            srcm.GetConfigurationRoute(out actionName, out controllerName, out routeValues);
            model.ConfigurationActionName = actionName;
            model.ConfigurationControllerName = controllerName;
            model.ConfigurationRouteValues = routeValues;
            return View(model);
        }
```

but there is a error `" A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?) "`

How can I slove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not be pass any parameter to action through siteMap.cofig in NOPCommerce because if you write action name with parameter in Action attribute of  **siteMapNode** it consider that is action name. 
so if want to call any action with parameter then crate a new Action for it and redirect from that.

```
//In Site Map 

    <siteMapNode title="Shipping rate" nopResource="Admin.Configuration.Shipping.Rate" controller="Shipping" action="SomeAction"/> 


//In Shipping Controller 


    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
         return RedirectToAction("ConfigureProvider", new { systemName = "Shipping.ByWeight" });
    }


    public ActionResult ConfigureProvider(string systemName)
    {

    }
```

In this way you can call your action.